# Exit time of an SDE

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stopping-times, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $\mathcal{O}$ be an open subset of $\mathbb R$ and $\mu\in\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{O})$. Consider the SDE
$$dX_t(\omega)= b(t, X_t(\omega), \omega)dt + \sigma(t, X_t(\omega))dW_t, \quad X_0\sim \mu.$$
Suppose that the coefficients are Lipschitz on $x$ (uniformly on the other variables) and bounded. Let
$$\tau_1:=\inf\{t\geq 0: X_t\notin \mathcal{O}\},$$
$$\tau_2:=\inf\{t\geq 0: X_t\notin \bar{\mathcal{O}}\},$$
where $\bar{\mathcal{O}}$ is the closure of $\mathcal{O}$.

My question is, what are the conditions on the coefficients and $\mathcal{O}$ to have $\tau_1=\tau_2$ a.s.?

Any references?

Thanks